# IOS 3D Transform like Clear app

Tags: ios, ios6

so what I want is to do the same thing Clear (http://www.realmacsoftware.com/clear/) does.
If I pan up or down it makes a new rectangle appear with a 3D visual effect.

I did manage to do this by using a translation and rotation transform along with changing the `m34` property.

The problem is that since I move 2 views (like Clear moving the rectangle that is showing on screen, and the rectangle appearing with the 3D visual effect), when the user stop touching the screen I use a

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                      delay:0
                    options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                 animations:^{
                         ...
                 } 
                 completion:nil];
```

to restore the views to a consistent state, either showing the new rectangle, or not (sliding it down), I can see the black background between the 2 views, meaning that the 2 rectangles are not being redrawn at same time.
How do I solve that?

Comment: This question would greatly benefit from some code and some screenshots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's difficult to answer your specific question without more details, but you can look at https://github.com/mpospese/MPFoldTransition for inspiration.

Mark Pospesel developed this wrapper to perform these kinds of folding transforms, and describes the process behind them in detail in his ["Anatomy of a folding animation"](http://markpospesel.wordpress.com/2012/05/10/anatomy-of-a-folding-animation/) blog post.

Comment: Thank you, I'm not with my mac right now, so I'll look into it when I get home.

But that is exactly what I need, the unfold with normal mode, but just half of it (cut the unfold image in the middle horizontally, and you will have the effect that I want).

Comment: The problem with my code is that, in the unfold image of your example, the image 1 and 2 are not glued together, so the image 2 starts moving before the image, leaving a gap between them where you can see the black background.

Comment: Hope you don't mind, but I edited in a link for where you can find Mark's description for how all this works. I remembered it from a talk I saw him give last year. He built it all to replicate Clear's interface, so it should do what Rodrigo wants here.

Comment: Thank you both, this last post explaining everything really helps a lot.
I didn't have time to read all of it, but it seems like he had the same problem I did, and seems likes he is doing the right way.

Comment: I did manage to implement what I wanted with CATransformLayer, although it solved some problems like the one of both view being tied together, I did lost a lot of performance.
Even In my simulator now I can move my mouse faster than the layers can be transformed.
Anyway to solve that?

Comment: Just if anyone run into the same problem, I did manage to solve what I wanted, it was not a performance problem, it was a matter of using the removeAllAnimations method on every layer.